# Sufficient and necessary condition for the integrability of a random variable

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, integral

Could anyone give me a hint on the following problem? Thanks!

Let $f$ be a random variable over a probability space $(\Omega,A,P)$. Show that

$f$ is integrable $\iff $ $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty P(\{|f|>n\}) < \infty.$

Note: Consider the sets $A_n:=\{n-1<|f|\le n\}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and the random variables $L:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (n-1)1_{A_n}$ and $R:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty n1_{A_n}$,$n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Should follow from the [Borel-Cantelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) lemma.